# How to define an array type in TypeScript which enforces more than one element of a given type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typing

I can create a type for an array of N element of string type:

```
type A = string[];
```

as well as a predefined number of elements, such as exactly 2 elements:

```
type A = [string, string];
```

What I am trying to have is a type that will accept 2 or more elements, but not just one or none.

```
type A = ?

A = ['a', 'b'];  // OK 
A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  // OK 
A = ['a', 'b', ... 'N'];  // OK 
A = ['a'];  // Error
A = [];  // Error
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to reassign a type?  Do you mean `let a: A = ['a', 'b']` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) to indicate that the tuple type is open-ended and may have zero or more additional elements of the array element type:

```
type A = [string, string, ...string[]];
```

The type `A` must start with two `string` elements and then it can have any number of `string` elements after that:

```
let a: A;
a = ['a', 'b'];  // OK 
a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  // OK 
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'N'];  // OK 
a = ['a'];  // error! Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
a = [];  // error!  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 2.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=44&pln=5&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBnYAnAlgOwOYBoo0s9CA6C4nXJAXVoG4AoJgGwmCgEMAuWZrgmQByLsMLCARsMZQoAenlQA8gGkoTQYiSjxUKXuEBjGQzmKV6zUJ1iJ0iSYkATQxEMA5U+aVqNWkTFZBSUIdHQAe3QAQigAZQiAV3QjaAALLhQoAEYoCHYAWwhsYAAKFABKKElEzmAudFwOKHQIAEdEzFasgCZrbWCLMMiYuQTk1KgMrIAGPMLissrq2qh6xubWjq6IXrIgA)